# Play WebRTC stream on WinForm C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, video-streaming, webrtc, uv4l

I have a linux server running WebRTC stream server from a webcam using uv4l with the next command

> uv4l --external-driver --device-name=video0

I can see it perfectly on a browser but I want to see it in a C# application, like a picturebox in the form (of course picturebox is not for it, it's only like a refence).

If someone knows a C library, nuget package, or any other control or whatever, they will be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This example displays a WebRTC video stream in a Windows Form https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/blob/master/examples/WebRTCExamples/WebRTCReceiver/Program.cs.

Comment: Now the problem is to get only the stream, uv4l is a web server and after clicking on a button it starts to stream.. only want the stream

Comment: I don't understand? You only want a video stream and not an audio stream? Or something else?

Comment: Only need the A/V stream, but, when running the server on the linux machine using the uv4l utility can't acces directly to it bacause is stopped, This utility have it's own http server and you have to open it in a browser and click on "run" to start streaming. I have three options here: 1) change to another streaming application like ffmpeg, etc.. but have a lot of lag.   2) Simulate the browser sending the signal to the uv4l to start streaming and then trying to open it with your sample    3) Try to start the utility without http server and directly streaming but can't find any option to this